# Raid 5 array in Ubuntu 22.04 fstab question

Tags: raid, fstab

I have nominal experience with Linux, but I have a raid array from an old NAS. I recently built a computer using the drives from the previous NAS as data drives (I installed a boot drive and installed Linux Ubuntu 22.04 and mdadm. Then I shutdown and installed the raid drives. Upon the startup it found the drives automatically and I can navigate to them with the GUI).

I can see the files etc. but when I try to copy them using GUI or cp at CLI I get an ownership issue. I did research and tried to chown of the files but am unable to find them at the command line (I could not figure out how to chown in the GUI). When I view the /etc/fstab file it only shows 2 drives listed and they are not part of the array.

I tried to use sudo mount /dev/sda/sda1/md125 ... /mnt and get an error not listed in the fstab file.

I am trying to figure out how to type what should be in the fstab file format syntax so I can get the array mounted to (/mnt/md125) change ownership then copy all the data to a separate dive.

Thank you in advance.

I do not know if any of this information below will be relevant but this is the list of hardware my computer in question is built from.

1. Intel I5 processor
2. 4 x 8 GB DDR4 Ram
3. 2 500 GB NVMe M.2 ssd
4. Gigabyte motherboard Z590 Chipset
5. 5 x 2TB Western Digital HDD
6. 1 6 port SATA controller card

Comment: AFAIK a RAID array's block device path would not normally include its member device(s) like `/dev/sda/sda1/md125` it would be something more like `/dev/md125`. Did you obtain that path using `mdadm --scan` or `mdadm --examine`?

Comment: The raid arrays on the data disk I saw using lsblk.